# Stabilize object on one axis only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to stabilize my object to not fall aside. This code works pretty good, but it also stabilize the object to not fall forward or backward.

Is there any possibility to restrict this to only one axis?

```cs
var deltaQuat = Quaternion.FromToRotation(_rBody.transform.up, Vector3.up);
deltaQuat.ToAngleAxis(out var angle, out var axis);
_rBody.AddTorque(-_rBody.angularVelocity * 2f, ForceMode.Acceleration);
_rBody.AddTorque(axis.normalized * angle * 5f, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the contrints in the rigidbody component:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but i need the rotations after all

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your goal is to constraint the rotation on a certain **local** axis.

You could probably do it somewhat similar to [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/404420/rigidbody-constraints-in-local-space.html) just not for positions but rotations going through [`Rigidbody.angularVelocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html).

```
// get the angularVelocity but in local space relative to the current rigidbody orientation
var localAngularVelocity = Quaternion.Inverse(rigidbody.rotation) * rigidbody.angularVelocity;

// get the euler space representation 
var localAngularEulers = localAngularVelocity.eulerAngles;

// now constraint according to your needs e.g. on the local forward axis
localEulerAngles.z = 0;

// now convert back and assign
rigidbody.angularVelocity = rigidbody.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(localAngularEulers);
```

---

*Note: Typing on smartphone so can't test it right now but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thank you so much! Will check that out on Monday!